# Group click related to expandable list view

Tags: android

As we know that we have performClick() method to generate click on a list view but we do not have the same kine of method to generate group click on an expandable list view. My requirement is that I want to generate group click on a particular group item of an expandable list view through my code.

Any workaround is appreciable.

Comment: can you in your terms what group click means

Comment: Do you have any solution for this issue? @AgarwalShankar he means the group header of an expandable list view group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a long time after the question was asked, but ran across this while I was having a similar issue. The solution I found was to use performItemClick instead.

I was trying:

```
List.getChildAt(position).performClick();
```

Instead I moved to:

```
List.performItemClick(List.getChildAt(position), position, List.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps...